# Python Checking if prime number

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

so...this is my code down below. I altered it all ways I can think of, but regardless of what I do it will ether say all the numbers are prime or all the numbers are not prime. I was hoping someone can point out the obvious error.
Currently this code says all numbers are not prime.
Thanks.

```
import math

x = int(input('Enter a number: '))

def isPrime(x):
  if x==2:
      print ("The number you entered is not Prime.")
      return

  i = 2
  x = int(math.sqrt(x)) 
  while i < x+1:
      if x%i==0:            
          print ("The number you entered is not Prime.")
          return
      i = i+1
  print ("This number is Prime")
  return

isPrime(x)
```

Comment: 2 is a prime number..

Comment: You need to fix the indentation, your code won't run as it stands.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Without it, we can only guess about the structure of your code.

Comment: There are about a million questions on SO regarding prime numbers and Python. I suggest you read through some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main bug is here:

```
x = int(math.sqrt(x))
```

You are altering `x`, so the subsequent divisibility checks incorrectly use this altered value of `x`.

You should store the square root in a different variable:

```
sqrt_x = int(math.sqrt(x)) 
while i < sqrt_x + 1:
   ...
```

Also, the number 2 is prime since it's only divisible by itself and one.

Answer (score 1):

the square root line should be removed, and a minor edit will make it work.

and yes, please fix your indent

```
import math

def isPrime(x): 

    i = 2
    #x = int(math.sqrt(x)) 
    while i < x:#x+1:
        z = x%i
        print "i: ", i, " x: ", x, "x%i: ", z
        if z==0:
            print ("The number you entered is not Prime.")
            return
        i = i+1
    print ("This number is Prime")
    return

x = int(input('Enter a number: '))
isPrime(x)
```